# Cytoscape.js how to layout connected nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js

I first create a graph with 100's of connected nodes. After all the nodes have been added I call

```
cy.layout({name: "dagre"});
```

Next, I'm creating 5 or so additional connected nodes I call layout on the nodes added but it doesn't lay them out as expected. Instead of being more like a tree all the nodes are in a straight line.

It looks like this:
[image]

```
var collection = cy.collection();
collection.merge(eles);
...
// I merge in another 5 newly created nodes.
// Next I call layout
collection.layout({
            name: "dagre", fit: false,
            boundingBox: {
                x1: mousex - width / 2, y1: mousey - height / 2, x2: mousex + width, y2: mousey + height
            },
            nodeSep: 30
        }).run();
```

But I expect it to look like the image below.

[image]

In order to get it to look like the above, I call layout shown below.

```
cy.layout({name: "dagre"});
```

I've looked through all the options for a dagre layout and can't find anything to make it create the tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** The dagre layout needs nodes and edges to calculate the right positions for the nodes, the way you use it, dagre thinks you give it 5 seperate nodes, which explains your wrong layout. The mistake lies here:

```
collection.merge(eles);          // here you should add all relevant nodes and edges
```

**End**

I have an example for you --->**[here](https://codepen.io/steevokovsky/pen/xQXPVV)**<---, just copy that and add your real data:

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [
    {
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "100px",
        shape: "rectangle",
        "background-color": "data(faveColor)"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "curve-style": "bezier",
        "control-point-step-size": 40,
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [
      { data: { id: "Top", faveColor: "#2763c4" } },
      { data: { id: "yes", faveColor: "#37a32d" } },
      { data: { id: "no", faveColor: "#2763c4" } },
      { data: { id: "Third", faveColor: "#2763c4" } },
      { data: { id: "Fourth", faveColor: "#56a9f7" } }
    ],
    edges: [
      { data: { source: "Top", target: "yes" } },
      { data: { source: "Top", target: "no" } },
      { data: { source: "no", target: "Third" } },
      { data: { source: "Third", target: "Fourth" } },
      { data: { source: "Fourth", target: "Third" } }
    ]
  },
  layout: {
    name: "random"
  }
}));

cy.ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    cy.nodes().layout({ name: 'dagre' }).run(); // this is what you do!!
    setTimeout(function () {
      cy.elements().layout({ name: 'dagre' }).run(); // this is what you should do!!
  },5000);
  }, 5000);
  
  
});
```

```css
body { 
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.17/cytoscape.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- cyposcape dagre -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks for this. The issue I have is when I call layout on a collection of nodes and not the entire graph, the collection doesn't layout as expected.
If I call it on cy, the entire graph get's laid out and the collection I of nodes I have get moved.

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe you don‘t call the layout function on all relevant elements, have you included thedges in the collection as i did in the above snippet?

Comment: Yes, I created all the proper components. You can see in the images what the top one looks like. It has the edges.

Comment: Can you show me the collection, that you run the layout on? I ask this, because the code seems to be fine...

Comment: I even tested it out, like i said previously, you run the layout only on nodes and not the added edges, that causes this layout and shouldn't be done

Comment: You are 100% correct! I wasn't added the edges to the collection. Once I added them, it did a correct layout. Thank you!